# Expo encountered a fatal error: Error while updating property 'text' in shadow node of type: RCTRawText

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Problem summary:

Goal : To deploy a functional and stable Android app on Google Play.

Development environment :
Expo 39.0.0

React Native 0.63

Physical device for testing : Honor 8x running on Android 10

Expected result : An Android app that doesn't crash

Actual result : `Expo encountered a fatal error: Error while updating property 'text' in shadow node of type: RCTRawText`

My Android app works perfectly without any warnings or error messages during development with Expo on a physical device Honor 8x/Android 10. When deployed in production, it crashes on all devices. adb logcat gives the above mentioned error message.

What have I tried :

1. Checked all  nodes that have a ternary operator or dynamic values dependent on state.
2. Empyting cache, deleting data and relaunching the app.
3. Asked for feedback from latest two other users. The app shows the same behaviour on their devices i.e. it crashes.
4. Run `expo start --no-dev --minify` to verify if it throws any errors or warnings.
5. Checked the apk on physical device with `adb install <path to apk>` . Tried this with multiple builds.

Minimum reproducible example : I can't isolate the source of the problem. Unfortunately I haven't installed Sentry. So I can't really share a specific code snippet that may be the root cause.

Defective app url on Google Play : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meetstargazers.application

Detailed Error Messages obtained by running `adb logcat`

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.meetstargazers.application/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Error while updating property 'text' in shadow node of type: RCTRawText

AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Error while updating property 'text' in shadow node of type: RCTRawText
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not happy with your attribute named "text". Try to find that attribute defined as "text" and check its value is correctly set. Moreover, android does not accept "&"  operations in values like {text: isValueMatched() && "abc"}, whereas it should be like {text: isValueMatched() ? "abc" : undefined}.